# Constrained multivariate random variable

Tags: multivariate-analysis

**Question 1**. Is is possible to generate a random variable $\mathbf{X} = \{X_1, \dots, X_N \}$ such that:

- for each instance $\mathbf{x} = \{x_1, \dots, x_N \}$ of $\mathbf{X}$ we have $\sum x_i = 1$ while
- $E\{ X_i \} = 0$ for all $i$?

**Question 2**. Alternatively, and related. Is it possible to build an $N \times M$ matrix $\mathbf{X}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} = 1$ for all $j$, and $\sum_{j=1}^M x_{ij} = 0$ for all $i$? I.e. such that each column adds up to 1 and each row adds up to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**
No. Think of $E(\sum X_i)$. From the first point it's 1, from the second it's 0.

**Question 2**
Also no. Think of grand total $\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^M x_{ij}$. If each column adds up to 1, grand total equals number of columns. If each row adds up to 0, grand total is 0 too.